# Horizontally Centering Absolute elements

Tags: html, css

I got this [codepen](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/rwWNqY), while it works perfectly, I cannot figure out why it cannot center the text in the middle of the containing box. Following is my code which center it vertically and now I want to center it horizontally too.

```
.container-box p{
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  height:40px;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  display:table;
  vertical-align:center;
}
```

Comment: You have to do it according to the width of your '.container-box'. Make the left of '.container-box p' 50% of the  '.container-box'. That will do.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLbENv check :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to give a `width` property for the `margin: auto`(centering) to work.

```
.container-box p {
  position:absolute;
  width: 25%; //add this
  margin:auto;
  ...
}
```

Also another main issue is that the `p` is center aligning to the container(`.container-box`) and not the image. **Make sure the image is covering that entire container**. You can do that by

```
.container-box img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now it will look like the text is in the center of the image but in literal the text is in the center of the container and your expanding the image to entire container.

Comment: How does `width` work here, as parent element/img is unknown.

Comment: The image is not the parent here, the `.container-box` is. So make the image cover the entire div and then it will look like the text is in the center of the image

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the *positioning*:

```css
* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

.container-box {
  display: inline-block; /* can also use "inline-flex" */
  position: relative; /* since one of the children is positioned absolute */
}

.container-box > img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  max-width: 100%; /* horizontal responsiveness */
  max-height: 100vh; /* vertical responsiveness */
}

.container-box > p {
  position: absolute; /* positioned relative to its parent */
  top: 50%; /* moved down by 50% of the parents height */
  left: 50%; /* moved right by 50% of the parents width */
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* moved left and up by half of its width and height to achieve the perfect center */
  height: 40px;
  background: Gray;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="">
  <p>This is a temp. Image.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .container-box p{
   position:absolute;
   margin:auto;
   width: 200px;
   ...
 }
```

Also give width 100% to the image.

```
.container-box img{
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Check this Modified version [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dROPGE)

Answer (score 0):

Use left:50% and top:50%. I cleaned up the CSS a little

```
.container-box p{
  position:absolute;
  height:40px;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:table;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```